# IJulia using Old Julia Installation

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I just upgraded from Julia 1.1.1 to 1.2.0*. Part of my workflow involves IJulia notebooks. Currently, anytime I try to launch and IJulia notebook, it launches a 1.1.1 kernel with no option for a 1.2.0 kernel, even if I launch the notebook from within 1.2.0

What extra steps do I need to take to fully upgrade to 1.2.0 and use the newer version in an IJulia notebook?

*To upgrade I put the Julia 1.2.0 folder in `/opt/` and changed the symlink in `/usr/local/bin/` to point to the new Julia executable

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out shortly after posting. The solution was to delete (or move, I chose to move) the `/.julia` directory and rebuild it with Julia 1.2.0, including reinstalling `IJulia`. The new version of Julia is now available for launching kernels for Jupyter notebooks

Comment: Note that you don't need to delete/move the `.julia` directory.  Simply `]add IJulia` in the new version should be sufficient.  Multiple versions happily co-exist together.

Comment: Just `]add IJulia` might not be enough if `IJulia` is already available on the system (e.g. for Julia 1.1 as in this example), you also have to rebuild IJulia (`]build IJulia`).